# Tags not saving for Joomla category custom component with the correct entry in the #__content_type for the Joomla 4 and Jooma 3

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-4.x, tags, categories

Created field type category in the custom component com_drawing
but not able to save the tags in the category(refer to the image)
[image]

Table entry in the table #__content_types

```
    
INSERT INTO #__content_types
(type_id, type_title, type_alias, `table`, rules, field_mappings, router, content_history_options)
VALUES(10035, 'drawingtable Category', 'com_drawing.category', '{"special":{"dbtable":"#__categories","key":"id","type":"CategoryTable","prefix":"Joomla\\\\Component\\\\Categories\\\\Administrator\\\\Table\\\\","config":"array()"},"common":   {"dbtable":"#__ucm_content","key":"ucm_id","type":"Corecontent","prefix":"Joomla\\\\CMS\\\\Table\\\\","config":"array()"}}', '{"common":{"core_content_item_id":"id","core_title":"title","core_state":"published","core_alias":"alias","core_created_time":"created_time","core_modified_time":"modified_time","core_body":"description", "core_hits":"hits","core_publish_up":"null","core_publish_down":"null","core_access":"access", "core_params":"params", "core_featured":"null", "core_metadata":"metadata", "core_language":"language", "core_images":"null", "core_urls":"null", "core_version":"version", "core_ordering":"null", "core_metakey":"metakey", "core_metadesc":"metadesc", "core_catid":"parent_id", "core_xreference":"null", "asset_id":"asset_id"}, "special":{"parent_id":"parent_id","lft":"lft","rgt":"rgt","level":"level","path":"path","extension":"extension","note":"note"}}', '', 'DrawingRouter::getCategoryRoute', '{"formFile":"administrator\\\\/components\\\\/com_categories\\\\/models\\\\/forms\\\\/category.xml", "hideFields":["asset_id","checked_out","checked_out_time","version","lft","rgt","level","path","extension"], "ignoreChanges":["modified_user_id", "modified_time", "checked_out", "checked_out_time", "version", "hits", "path"],"convertToInt":["publish_up", "publish_down"], "displayLookup":[{"sourceColumn":"created_user_id","targetTable":"#__users","targetColumn":"id","displayColumn":"name"},{"sourceColumn":"access","targetTable":"#__viewlevels","targetColumn":"id","displayColumn":"title"},{"sourceColumn":"modified_user_id","targetTable":"#__users","targetColumn":"id","displayColumn":"name"},{"sourceColumn":"parent_id","targetTable":"#__categories","targetColumn":"id","displayColumn":"title"}]}');
```

When trying to select tags and save the category in J3 component it faces the following error
[image]

Does anyone have an Idea what can be the reason behind that?

I have checked and found that in the below file /j3/libraries/src/Helper/TagsHelper.php
in the  `public function postStoreProcess(TableInterface $table, $newTags = array(), $replace = true)` function

$this->typeAlias is `com_drawing.drawingtables.category` instead of `com_drawing.category`

Tried to add the below line in the Table class but did not solve the error
`JTableObserverTags::createObserver($this, array('typeAlias' => 'com_drawing.drawingtable'));`

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue because my component has two tables and each table has a Joomla category field.
which are as follows

`<field name="category" extension="com_drawing.drawingtables" type="category" label="COM_DRAWING_FORM_LBL_DRAWINGTABLE_CATEGORY" description="COM_DRAWING_FORM_DESC_DRAWINGTABLE_CATEGORY" hint="COM_DRAWING_FORM_LBL_DRAWINGTABLE_CATEGORY"/>`

and

```
    `<field name="tootcategory" extension="com_drawing.tools" type="category" label="COM_DRAWING_FORM_LBL_TOOL_TOOTCATEGORY" description="COM_DRAWING_FORM_DESC_TOOL_TOOTCATEGORY" hint="COM_DRAWING_FORM_LBL_TOOL_TOOTCATEGORY"/>`
```

So I need to insert two separate entries in the **#__content_types** table as below

`INSERT INTO #__content_types (type_id, type_title, type_alias,` table`, rules, field_mappings, router, content_history_options) VALUES(10035, 'drawingtable Category', 'com_drawing.drawingtables.category', '{"special":{"dbtable":"#__categories","key":"id","type":"CategoryTable","prefix":"Joomla\\\\Component\\\\Categories\\\\Administrator\\\\Table\\\\","config":"array()"},"common":   {"dbtable":"#__ucm_content","key":"ucm_id","type":"Corecontent","prefix":"Joomla\\\\CMS\\\\Table\\\\","config":"array()"}}', '{"common":{"core_content_item_id":"id","core_title":"title","core_state":"published","core_alias":"alias","core_created_time":"created_time","core_modified_time":"modified_time","core_body":"description", "core_hits":"hits","core_publish_up":"null","core_publish_down":"null","core_access":"access", "core_params":"params", "core_featured":"null", "core_metadata":"metadata", "core_language":"language", "core_images":"null", "core_urls":"null", "core_version":"version", "core_ordering":"null", "core_metakey":"metakey", "core_metadesc":"metadesc", "core_catid":"parent_id", "core_xreference":"null", "asset_id":"asset_id"}, "special":{"parent_id":"parent_id","lft":"lft","rgt":"rgt","level":"level","path":"path","extension":"extension","note":"note"}}', '', 'DrawingRouter::getCategoryRoute', '{"formFile":"administrator\\\\/components\\\\/com_categories\\\\/models\\\\/forms\\\\/category.xml", "hideFields":["asset_id","checked_out","checked_out_time","version","lft","rgt","level","path","extension"], "ignoreChanges":["modified_user_id", "modified_time", "checked_out", "checked_out_time", "version", "hits", "path"],"convertToInt":["publish_up", "publish_down"], "displayLookup":[{"sourceColumn":"created_user_id","targetable":"#__users","targetColumn":"id","displayColumn":"name"},{"sourceColumn":"access","targetTable":"#__viewlevels","targetColumn":"id","displayColumn":"title"},{"sourceColumn":"modified_user_id","targetable":"#__users","targetColumn":"id","displayColumn":"name"},{"sourceColumn":"parent_id","targetTable":"#__categories","targetColumn":"id","displayColumn":"title"}]}');`

And

`INSERT INTO #__content_types (type_id, type_title, type_alias,` table`, rules, field_mappings, router, content_history_options) VALUES(10035, 'drawingtable Category', 'com_drawing.tools.category', '{"special":{"dbtable":"#__categories","key":"id","type":"CategoryTable","prefix":"Joomla\\\\Component\\\\Categories\\\\Administrator\\\\Table\\\\","config":"array()"},"common":   {"dbtable":"#__ucm_content","key":"ucm_id","type":"Corecontent","prefix":"Joomla\\\\CMS\\\\Table\\\\","config":"array()"}}', '{"common":{"core_content_item_id":"id","core_title":"title","core_state":"published","core_alias":"alias","core_created_time":"created_time","core_modified_time":"modified_time","core_body":"description", "core_hits":"hits","core_publish_up":"null","core_publish_down":"null","core_access":"access", "core_params":"params", "core_featured":"null", "core_metadata":"metadata", "core_language":"language", "core_images":"null", "core_urls":"null", "core_version":"version", "core_ordering":"null", "core_metakey":"metakey", "core_metadesc":"metadesc", "core_catid":"parent_id", "core_xreference":"null", "asset_id":"asset_id"}, "special":{"parent_id":"parent_id","lft":"lft","rgt":"rgt","level":"level","path":"path","extension":"extension","note":"note"}}', '', 'DrawingRouter::getCategoryRoute', '{"formFile":"administrator\\\\/components\\\\/com_categories\\\\/models\\\\/forms\\\\/category.xml", "hideFields":["asset_id","checked_out","checked_out_time","version","lft","rgt","level","path","extension"], "ignoreChanges":["modified_user_id", "modified_time", "checked_out", "checked_out_time", "version", "hits", "path"],"convertToInt":["publish_up", "publish_down"], "displayLookup":[{"sourceColumn":"created_user_id","targetable":"#__users","targetColumn":"id","displayColumn":"name"},{"sourceColumn":"access","targetTable":"#__viewlevels","targetColumn":"id","displayColumn":"title"},{"sourceColumn":"modified_user_id","targetable":"#__users","targetColumn":"id","displayColumn":"name"},{"sourceColumn":"parent_id","targetTable":"#__categories","targetColumn":"id","displayColumn":"title"}]}');`